# Dynamic Function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have following methods under API_SERVICE.

```
export const API_SERVICE = {
  post: post,
  get: get,
  put: put,
  patch: patch
};
```

Export above method from API_SERVICE.

So IF I want to post I'll call like:

```
API_SERVICE.post(url , data) / API_SERVICE.patch(url , data)
```

Here my question is I have one form for both update and create. Both function are same. I want to reuse this code.

How to call this methods **dynamically** ?

Below showing error:

```
[isEdit ? API_SERVICE.patch : API_SERVICE.post]( url , data ).then(response => ....
```

> Error: *(intermediate value)] is not a function*

Comment: Use parentheses `(` `)` instead of quare brackets?: `(isEdit ? API_SERVICE.patch : API_SERVICE.post)(url , data)`

Comment: how do you import it?

Comment: I think this should work ```API_SERVICE[`${isEdit ? API_SERVICE.post : API_SERVICE.get}`](url , data)```

Comment: @Mohsen: No, because `API_SERVICE.post` is a function and so converting it to a string doesn't make sense. This would work: `API_SERVICE[isEdit ? 'post' : 'get'](url , data)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is **not** a question about React, but a question about JavaScript.

In JavaScript, you can call methods in this way:

```js
const foo = num => num + 1;
const bar = num => num * 2;

(true ? foo : bar)(2);
// get 3

(false ? foo : bar)(2);
// get 4
```

This might achieve what you are expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the method in another way let me give an example:

```
const req = await fetch(url,{
  method : isEdit ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringfy(data),
  headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call It dynamically in return statement you have to use curly braces so it should look something like this:

```
{ isEdit ? ApiService.patch(url, data) : ApiService.post(url, data) }
```

I don't think that you can use then() inside {} so your function
Should be async and do it's job by it self, change some state for example
Regards
Adrian

Comment: *"If you want to call It dynamically in return statement you have to use curly braces "* That's not correct. Maybe you are thinking of interpolation in JSX?